# Linux user-space vs kernel -space file system performance

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems

Is there a performance impact from using a user space file system vs a kernel space filesystem? I ask because I have a friend that refuses to use user space file systems because of a performance impact. I've done some research but cannot find any benchmarks of user-space vs kernel-space file systems.

Comment: He's arguing that user-space filesystems are *faster*?

Comment: If he doesn't use kernel-space file systems, how on earth does he boot his computer?

Comment: We kind of figured as much. Sure, the performance is usually slightly worse with a userspace filesystem, as @sysadmin1138 noted in his answer. But performance is not the _sole_ criterion for choosing a filesystem, and so sometimes using one is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a research paper out there titled, *Performance and Extension of User Space File Systems* by Aditya Rajgarhia (Stanford) and Ashih Gehani (SRI) that goes into exactly what you're looking for. It is easily locatable.

The conclusions reached match my own perceptions of this that user-space file-systems (FUSE specifically) do perform measurably worse than kernel-space filesystems. They go into much more detail about their findings.